# Create multiple columns by splitting value from other column with one assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is DataFrame as:

```
timestamp                filename
2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023/12/20/1703056183.log
```

How to create new columns "year","month","day"  in one assignment by splitting  of "filename" column?

Wished result is :

```
timestamp                year month day  filename
2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023 12    20   2023/12/20/1703056183.log
```

Comment: In your question you don't change the filename, however the currently accepted answer does. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @mozway - now not.

Comment: @jezrael then your answer is really convoluted just to avoid doing the simplest thing. Would you really do this in real life? I doubt it.

Comment: In the case your timestamp is always going to match the date in the file name it'd probably be significantly less work (computationally faster) to get the year, month, and day parts from the datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n` parameter for split first 3 `/`, for expected order add [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

*Notice: Filename column is changed*

```
df[['year','month','day','filename']] = df.pop('filename').str.split('/', n=3, expand=True)
print (df)
                 timestamp  year month day        filename
0  2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023    12  20  1703056183.log
```

For your ouput with `filename` column in your order use:

```
df[['year','month','day','_']] = df['filename'].str.split('/', n=3, expand=True)

df = df[df.columns.drop(['filename','_']).union(['filename'], sort=False)]
print (df)
                 timestamp  year month day                   filename
0  2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023    12  20  2023/12/20/1703056183.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and slice to only keep the first 3 columns:

```
df[['year', 'month', 'day']] = (df['filename'].str.split('/', n=3, expand=True)
                                .iloc[:, :3]
                                )
```

Alternatively, use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) that can allow you to specify that you expect numbers:

```
df[['year', 'month', 'day']] = df['filename'].str.extract(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)')
```

Output:

```
                 timestamp                   filename  year month day
0  2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023/12/20/1703056183.log  2023    12  20
```

And if you really want the filename column in the end, just add:

```
df['filename'] = df.pop('filename')
```

Output:

```
                 timestamp  year month day                   filename
0  2023-12-20 10:09:52.011  2023    12  20  2023/12/20/1703056183.log
```